# Can't get current device location

Tags: android, latitude-longitude, locationmanager

I am trying to get current location of my android phone and display the longitude and latitude in a toast. Here is a function I wrote. While debugging the code I see that the control never goes inside onLocationChanged function.

From the following android documentation it looks like, when I call "locationMgr.requestLocationUpdates", it should call the callback function onLocationChanged. But that does not seem to happen in my code. 
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/location/currentlocation.html

I checked my phone has GPS turned on. I can not figure out what is wrong in the following code. Please help.

```
  public void getCurrentLocation(){
            LocationManager locationMgr;
    locationMgr = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    LocationListener listener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
           // A new location update is received.  Do something useful with it  

                    String latitude = "latitude: " + location.getLatitude();
                    String longitude = "longitude: " + location.getLongitude();
                    String toastString = "location is" + latitude + "," +longitude;
                    Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),toastString,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        @Override  
          public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {  
           // No code here  
          }  

          @Override  
          public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {  
           // No code here  
          }  

          @Override  
          public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,Bundle extras)   
          {  
           // No code here  
          }  
    };

    locationMgr.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0, 0, listener);
}
```

I also have following two lines in my Manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Thank you for your help.

I am using Eclipse and my phone(OS: Thuderbolt) has API level 15, target 4.0.4.

Comment: Sometime restarting a device helps. Just check if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. I tried restarting my phone. It still does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was google-play-services library.
I had to download the library code and compile it in eclipse. Then I added the path to the library in my project. This solved the problem. 
Earlier I had included the google-play-services .jar file in my project, but it was not working. Not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

There are several reasons that you are not getting location.

1.) If you are trying to get location on emulator. Then you have to manually push the coordinates using DDMS.

2.) If You are checking it on device and still you are not getting location. Then as you said that you are expecting it from GPS. Then you should have Clear sky view to get that. As GPS receiver dont work under roofs or under some hinderances. They must have sky view.

3.) You can get location from using wi-fi or cell-Tower. Also you can opt for Last known location if location accuracy is not as much important.

What i think is that may be second point will resolve your problem.

Comment: I am not using the emulator. I am using my android phone. I think the phone receiving GPS because I can open the Google Map app on my phone and it is able to track my current location. So I conclude that the GPS is working fine. Am I wrong here?

Comment: yes because google maps uses caching and your previous known location if they didn't get your new location thats the only reason that you are able to see google maps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is example i wrote that uses LocationManager to get the location data every two minutes. Its not perfect but should be sufficient to solve your issue: It can be found [here](http://androidhappenings.blogspot.com/2013/03/android-app-development-201-1st.html)
Focus on:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {
    this.location=location;
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Timer ourtimer = new Timer();
    TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        int cnt=1;
        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                    Double longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    Double altitude = location.getAltitude();
                    Float accuracy = location.getAccuracy();
                    textView.setText("Latitude: " + latitude + "\n" + "Longitude: " + longitude+ "\n" + "Altitude: " + altitude + "\n" + "Accuracy: " + accuracy + "meters"+"\n" + "Location Counter: " + cnt);
                    try {
                        jsonData = new JSONObject();
                        jsonData.put("Latitude", latitude);
                        jsonData.put("Longitude", longitude);
                        jsonData.put("Altitude", altitude);
                        jsonData.put("Accuracy", accuracy);

                        System.out.println(jsonData.toString()); //not required, for testing only   
                        if(url!=null) {
                            new HttpPostHandler().execute();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    cnt++;
                }
            });
        }};
    ourtimer.schedule(timerTask, 0, 120000);
```